# Popout Map for Google Maps application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I've written a single-page application using Google Maps in conjunction with AngularJS.

In short I have three columns - one filled with tools, one with a table of data, and the final is the geographical representation of the table's data.
The data is updated every minute.

The users all have multiple monitors, and it's been requested that adding the ability to have the map on one window, and table on the other - so that the map can have more real estate and we can add more columns to the table.

The solution that I really want is to create a new window using JS, and move the map's DIV to this window.

This works in chrome and it works exactly as I expected - moving the div doesn't break google map's or Angular's ties to the DOM, as the DIV is never deleted nor cloned, just moved within the DOM.

However IE11 treats the new window as an entirely separate document, and disallows the use of appendChild (throwing heirachy exceptions).

---

I have tried using adoptNode to move the node to the new window's document, but IE throws a 'No such interface supported' error on the adoptNode call, however IE allows you to use adoptNode to move the node between iframes, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/nx9u4y9w/9/
This works in FF/Chrome.

```
var f1 = window.f1,
    f2 = window.f2,
    pop = window.open(f2.location.href, 'pop'),
    x = 0;
window.fx = function(o) {
    var source = f1,
        target = f2,
        map;
    if (x++ == 1) {
        source = f2;
        target = pop;

        o.disabled = true;
    }
    map = source.document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var adopted = target.document.adoptNode(map);
    target.document.body.appendChild(adopted);
}
```

---

Is there a simple way to get this working in IE11?

I wanted to avoid creating a new HTML page to load into the window, as it'd cause a serious break in the UX whilst the map reloads, plus it'll there's the code overhead of having to create an intra-browser messaging using postMessage, etc.

Comment: Take a look at [`adoptNode`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdfwkmx.php). But basically, when "map" is a `google.maps.Map` your approach shouldn't work in any browser, because the maps-API internally uses a reference to the document where the map has been created, the map will lose the functionality.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I just tested in firefox and it works the same as chrome - it happily lets you appendchild to the new window's document. the adoptNode method works fine in chrome and FF, but IE throws a "No such interface supported" error when you try to call adoptNode from the original window.

Comment: I've tried it before (moving of the map) and it didn't work because of document.reference. As it seems there has been a change in the API, it works now. Example that works for me in IE too(uses iframes, but basically it's the same, it moves the map between different documents): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nx9u4y9w/

Comment: that's rather weird. it 100% works with iframes, but it doesn't work for popout windows: http://jsfiddle.net/nx9u4y9w/9/. that works in FF/Chrome, but the adoptNode for the popout window fails in IE.